# Turn on auto_update_statistics_async for Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure-sql-database

I'm trying to turn on auto_update_statistics_async option for current azure sql database.

```
DECLARE @dbname NVARCHAR(128) = quotename(db_name())
EXEC ('alter database ' + @dbname + ' SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC ON')
```

But it is not work, because of error

> Msg 40530, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The ALTER DATABASE statement must
>   be the only statement in the batch.

CURRENT predicate for azure sql is not available

DATABASEPROPERTYEX is available only for not async statistics (if i correctly understand)

Is there a way to receive current DB name in the same statement or other way to turn on auto_update_statistics_async option?

Answer (score 2):

This is only supported in SQL Azure V12. Looks like your server is running in SQL Azure V11. Upgrade your server to V12, and the Current keyword is not supported in SQL Azure. The other thing to note is that the statement should be executed from the user database context if not already.